# Is there a difference between the adjoint and conjugate?

Tags: operators, terminology, dirac-equation

Is there a difference between the [adjoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint) and [conjugate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugation)? I have recently started some work for a quantum field theory module and I'm wondering if there is a difference between the adjoint or conjugate of an equation such as the Dirac equation.

Comment: complex conjugate and transposed versus just conjugate?

Comment: I'm unsure, my lecture notes just refer to the conjugate of the Dirac equation and also its adjoint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **adjoint** of an operator is obtained by taking the complex conjugate of the operator followed by transposing it.

i.e.,  $(A)^\dagger_{ij}=\left((A)^T_{ij}\right)^*=\left((A_{ij})^*\right)^T=A_{ji}^*$

You can do it in any order. **The adjoint of an operator is the infinite dimensional generalization of conjugate transpose**, where you find the transpose of an operator (in matrix form this is done by $A_{ij}^T=A_{ji}$) and then take the complex conjugate of it.

Now, the **complex conjugate** of an operator is obtained by reversing the sign of the imaginary term in the operator representation (or in it's Matrix form). It's like finding the conjugate of the complex number $a+ib$ as $a-ib$. The complex conjugate of an operator $A$ in this discussion is represented as $A^*$ (some textbooks show other notations also).

In quantum mechanics, the operators corresponding to (real) physical state are Hermitian in nature since the eigen values corresponding to the eigen kets of a Hermitian operator are real. Hermitian operators are called self-adjoint operators since the operator and it's adjoint are the same. i.e., if $A$ is Hermitian, then $A^\dagger=A$. Now, in a complex vector space, the adjoint and complex conjugate of an operator has the same meaning.

Comment: I don't have a deep understanding of different types of matrices and their significance, so can you explain  "the eigen values corresponding to the eigen kets of a Hermitian operator" in simpler / layman terms. Also, what does it mean to apply Hermitian operators and why not some other type of operators on qubits in quantum computing.